# Huge holes when using the mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, mirror-modifier

Been having this issue, trying to make an instersection with two semicircles and I'm using the mirror modifier to do so. However, when I do that, the best result I get gives me these huge holes. Am I missing something here? How do I fix this so that they are perfectly aligned and do not clip into each other?

[image]

Comment: Can u provide blend file?

Answer (score 1):

Take a cube rotated at a 45 degree angle and use a Boolean Modifier to create a cutout of your tunnel with the perfect shape.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: I just noticed this, in these images my object is actually rotated a bit in Object mode, which is why I have to mirror along the Y and Z axes instead of X and Y

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, create yout half cylinder, then an empty. Give your cylinder a *Mirror* modifier, enable the X and Y *Bisect* option, choose the empty as *Mirror* Object:

[image]

Now rotate the cylinder 45° on Z, you have your intersection:

[image]